# apache and mysql consuming too much memory with worker mpm on amazon ec2 instance with t2.medium

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, apache-2.4, httpd

I am using ec2 instance after using it for a while it automatically stops working then afterwards I checked the log error,I got the following errors.
So the whole instances stops working then i need to manually reboot it from management console.

```
[Sun Apr 15 06:49:37.993406 2018] [mpm_worker:error] [pid 2927:tid 139830901221440] (12)Cannot allocate memory: AH00283: fork: Unable to fork new $k new process
[Sun Apr 15 06:49:37.993406 2018] [mpm_worker:error] [pid 2927:tid 139830901221440] (12)Cannot allocate memory: AH00283: fork: Unable to fork new $k new process
[Sun Apr 15 06:49:37.993406 2018] [mpm_worker:error] [pid 2927:tid 139830901221440] (12)Cannot allocate memory: AH00283: fork: Unable to fork new $k new process
```

This is my mpm_worker configuration

```
<IfModule mpm_worker_module>
       StartServers          4
       MinSpareThreads       20
       MaxSpareThreads      40
       MaxClients           200
       MaxRequestsPerChild  4500
</IfModule>
```

Comment: You're running out of memory. Chances are your server doesn't have enough RAM for 200 Apache clients.

Comment: what is the activity of the server? How many requests you get? How large is the database? There are various reasons for OOM.

Comment: I suspect if you read a little wider in the logs you may find the problem. The "$k" part of "unable to fork new $k new processes" also looks odd and suggests something may be misconfigured.